# Removing spikes from multiple onboard power supplies

Tags: noise, decoupling

I have a board that is based around an STM32F303 and am using the onboard ADC/DAC, fed by a 3V power supply derived from a USB 5V input. The 5V also feeds a module, RD0515, which creates +/- 15V for opamps on the board. My problem is that the RD0515 also creates quite substantial spikes of about 2uS width and repetition rate of 20uS.

These are finding their way through to the analog supply pins on the STM32 at around 100mV amplitude and screwing up measurements. The board is 4 layer (GND and 3V internal planes) and has plenty of capacitor decoupling.

Is there a better way of getting the +/- 15V that will not cause such problems?

Comment: What do the analog supply pins connect to? A circuit would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RD0515](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/468/RD-8370.pdf) is a switching type converter. As such it is not surprising that it produces spikes in an unoptimized design. There are several things you can do to help with this situation.

1. At the input side to the converter make sure to apply a very low impedance high value capacitor to supply the input current surges as the internal circuit switches on and off. It may also be necessary to place some inductor or power type ferrite bead in series with the 5V supply and the input of the converter. The added capacitor should be as close to the converter as possible and would be on the converter side of any series inductance added.
2. On the outputs you may need to add a low pass filter to clean out spikes before the +/- 15V goes to other circuitry. This may need to be a multi stage filter with several series inductors/ferrite power beads with intermediate capacitors to GND.
3. An alternate for the outputs would be to run your analogue circuits on +/- 12V and place low current linear regulators (7812/7912 types) between the converter and the analogue circuits.

I can add the comment that the RD0515 is part of RECOM's "econoline". The parts are small, convenient and have attractive prices. But for this you do give up some on how much filtering that the manufacturer puts inside the converter. The econoline is most certainly designed to be adequate for many applications that do not care about some switching spikes. On the other hand if you select this type part then you take on the burden of cleaning things up to be suitable for your specific design.

Also be aware that the RD0515 part does not have regulated outputs. As such the output voltages can change with load current variation and input voltage variations. If your analogue circuit designs have a dependency on the accuracy of the DC voltages and have low tolerance to power supply variations you may very well want to look at the option (3) above.

Lastly be aware that this part should have a minimum load of 10% of its rated capacity in order to meet the data sheet performance specifications.

Comment: Thanks. I notice that Murata do pin compatibles. Ideally I would like a drop in replacement (it's socketed). Time to read some data sheets...

Comment: BTW, the Murata device NMK0515 seems to have considerably better specs from noise and regulation POV and is not much more expensive - I'll try one and report back

Answer (score 1):

Separate the supply lines using inductors.

Inductors block AC, their impedance increases with frequency. The noise is being coupled along the supply lines to the power line that feeds the device, so an inductor in that line will block the AC. The technique is sometimes used to create, to separate analogue and digital grounds to ensure that high frequency noise (voltage spikes) doesn't propagate on to the AC ground.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a bit more information to this, such as what happens when you put an inductor and what happens when you don't.

Comment: Inductors block AC, their impedance increases with frequency. The noise is being coupled along the supply lines to the power line that feeds the device, so an inductor in that line will block the AC.  The technique is some times used to create, to separate analogue and digital grounds to ensure that high frequency noise (voltage spikes) doesn't propagate on to the AC ground.

Comment: Add it to the body of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing your needs:

- +5V In
- +15V Out VERY CLEAN
- -15V Out VERY CLEAN

If I was starting from scratch and NOT forced to use the RD0515, then I would do the following concept for both +15V and -15V power rails (the following only shows the +15V):

1) +5V IN

to

2) Boost/Inverter Switching Voltage Regulator (or Module) with +16V to +18V OUT (depends on "drop out" voltage of LDO in step#4). 18V is fairly common, but if you have a variable output then tweak the voltage a little closer to the LDO drop out.

to

3) power filter (possibly a pi-filter and ferrite bead)

to

4) low drop out (LDO) linear voltage regulator.

to

5) +15V OUT

to

6) capacitor(s) and analog rail

Comment: Thanks. I eventually did it with the NMK0515 and a couple of 22u caps plus 100u inductors. Getting around 40mVpp of noise, which is tolerable.